# Jenkins section "people" is empty

Tags: jenkins

I have problem with jenkins "people" section being empty. When my project builds i can see who did latest commits etc. I even can click on the user and change his settigs like email etc. When i go to "people" tab i don't see anyone there.

I've tried to update my Subversion Plugin but it didn't take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the people part. What you see is the list of committers.
The people who will be listed in people section are Jenkins Users, i.e people who are registered to jenkins. Not the ones committing to some project.

To have people listed up, Proceed as below:

`Manage Jenkins>Configure System`

In Access Control: Security Relam. Opt for `Jenkins's own user database`

And check `Allow users to sign up`

`Save` the changes.

Now in `Manage Jenkins` you will have `Manage Users` option. You can create users here. They will be listed in `People` page.

Comment: Hi Jelsy, according to [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/The+'People'+listing) People tab should display commiters

Comment: @user2182067 AFAIK this depends whether the build is triggered by a commit. If a commit is triggering the build, then the user who triggered the build via commit will get listed in peoples page. Let me explain it further, the committers are not part of build system as long as they don't trigger any action on it, so they won't be listed but you can see commiters listed w.r.t specific project.

Comment: my builds are triggered by commits (SCM polling). I've also looked into jenkins error logs but its empty.

Comment: @user2182067, My experience is totally from using Git plugin, the builds are triggered from a gihub hook. Have you checked any other jenkins server that is online. A lot of open source projects have their jenkins servers public. Or mind shooting the question in Jenkins mailing list. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jenkinsci-users ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest Jenkins release may have changed some of the locations shown in the first reply.  Try using:

1. Manage Jenkins, Configure Global Security
2. In the Access Control: Security Realm section, select the radio button for "Jenkins's own user database"
3. Check the checkbox for "Allow users to sign up"

Our "People" page is still blank however.  I'm not sure why.